# Windows 8 App Cert Kit no longer runs?

Tags: windows-8, microsoft-metro, app-certification-kit

I am trying to do the App Cert check on my Metro app, but it won't run anymore! Anybody else having this same issue? I've searches all over the Internet, with not even a single related result.

It ran successfully a few hours ago, but now it just won't run at all. The spinning cursor shows, indicating that it's about to open - but it doesn't.

I've tried restarting my computer, opening/closing visual studio, opening/closing my app. It just doesn't run. I've tried running as Admin, I've even tried running it from its actual location - instead of just using the shortcut icon on the Start screen - but it just won't run.

What to do?

Comment: Does it appear for a few seconds and then disappear in Task Manager?

Comment: I didn't see it. But I checked again, and noticed that `Windows Problem Reporting` appeared and then disappeared. So I'm gonna go check that.

Comment: @BoltClock I checked out Windows Problem Reporting and viewed temp copy of dumped crash files: `Files that help describe the problem
AppCompat.txt
WERInternalMetadata.xml
memory.hdmp
triagedump.dmp
` but they didn't help describe the problem. They just show a bunch of other files, but didn't see any error messages or stuff like that.

Comment: @BoltClock Yep. I just saw it appear then disappear in Task Manager.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I managed to solve this problem.

Run CMD.exe as an Admin, and enter the following commands:

- `cd C:\Program Files\Windows Kits\8.0\App Certification Kit`
- `appcert.exe reset`

CMD should now say:

> Successfully reset the testing configuration.

Now, enter:

- `appcertui`

The Windows App Certification Kit should now appear.

Comment: Brilliant! We ran into the same problem where it would look for an older build of the application (probably cached the version somewhere). We actually used the command-line appcert.exe and the error looked like this: `Unhandled Exception: System.IO.DirectoryNotFoundException: Could not find a part of the path 'C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\FooApp_old.version.number.0_x64__f9423lkjd58qa\AppXManifest.xml'. at System.IO.__Error.WinIOError(Int32 errorCode, String maybeFullPath) at System.IO.FileStream.Init(String path, FileMode mode, FileAccess access, Int32 rights, Boolean useRights ...`