# Windows Store App Cert Kit Fails to Start

Tags: windows-runtime, windows-store-apps, winrt-xaml, windows-8.1, app-certification-kit

The Windows Store App Cert kit fails to start.

Normally the flow is:

- Start App Cert Kit
- Choose Windows Store Application
- Choose App
- Choose Certs to Run
- Run Certs
- Save results

Currently, it fails just before 'Choose App'.

I get this result:

[image: App Cert Fail Message]

I have tried uninstalling and reinstalling, installed all updates, [running `appcert.exe reset`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12480949/windows-8-app-cert-kit-no-longer-runs). All to no avail.

I think it may have to do with the same issue I get with the Windows Store app. I have 38 languages installed (our app supports all of them) and the Windows Store app doesn't like it. I've had to escalate with customer support repeatedly for this, and have not had it resolved properly. I wonder if the same issue applies here.

Comment: I have the same issue on Windows 8.1 just after I updated the Windows SDK to the new version as required by the App Certi Kit. It only happens when trying to use the "Validate a Windows Store App" feature.

Answer (score 0):

So I was unable to start the UI, but I was still able to run the `appcert` by manually calling it on the command line [as described here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh694081.aspx). It worked fine. One thing to note is that between each attempt, make sure to run `appcert.exe reset`.